# I put on Vaseline during sahri but while I was praying Fajr I felt that the Vaseline had accidentally got into my mouth.Is my fast still valid

Tags: salat, sawm, ramadan

I suffer from OCD and every time I apply Vaseline on my dry lips I feel that I swallowed it . So yesterday i put on Vaseline on my lips during sahri so that even if it got into my mouth I can wash it on time . But during I was praying my Fajr Salah i felt that the Vaseline had stayed in my mouth and i couldn't break my Salah so after i finished my Fajr prayer I washed my mouth. But still I am unsure if it broke my fast because I was not able to wash my mouth on time

Comment: Salam, accidental ingestion of Vaseline during fasting does not invalidate the fast as long as it was unintentional. In Islamic jurisprudence, unintentional consumption or ingestion of substances that are not food or drink does not break the fast.